# How To Stop A SSIS Package Step In SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

I have a SQL Server Agent job that runs on daily basis and the first step in the job is to execute a SSIS package. For the past a few days the step 1 is being running endlessly. Is there anyway that I can shut down the running step?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Integration Service Catalogs, right click

[image]

Open 'Active Operations', there is 'Stop' button.

You can also pull the 'All Execution' Report from Catalog or run query.

```
-- Status = created (1), running (2), canceled (3), failed (4), pending (5), ended unexpectedly (6), succeeded (7), stopping (8), and completed (9) 
SELECT * FROM SSISDB.[catalog].[executions]
```

Don't have enough information can help you, what is the 1st step1 message in the job step history? In the job properties, click the step, in the advanced tab, what is the number of Retry attempts? No information how you setup job steps, packages?

Comment: Surprisingly, I'm not seeing any active operation here, even through from the job history it is showing the step is being running

Comment: Looking at your job steps, how come you have 2 step1? Any chance 2nd step1 is a retry attempts and it is failed?

Comment: That's my question. I checked the setting and it does not have any retry set up. Even if there was a retry when the retry failed the original should also fail rather than running right?

Comment: You can check SQL Server Activity Monitor as well. If I were you, I would fix error why step1 failed first.